# Playing Flash Files (SWF/FLV) in C# Win Form

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, windows-7, flash

I have spent lots of time in doing google, but everywhere i have found only 2 way to play swf/flv in win form application and both are not working for me.

1.Using Shockwave flash object:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/635085/Playing-Flash-Files-SWF-in-Csharp-Form

I am able to add "Shockwave flash object" to toolbar but when i drop it on form, my visual studio gets restart immediately..

2.Playing swf in webbrowser control in winform:
This is also not working.

NOTE: I have done re-installation of flash player but still issue is same. Adobe Flash Player 13.0.0.182 is installed on my machine.

I have event though of converting swf/flv into video and then play in some player in c# but for that also i am not able to find any free library/code to convert flv/swf to video.

Please provide any link or suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the solution..
I had to install the IE specific version of flash player to get the things working correctly..

Comment: How can I check it? I have the same issue. I am working with chrome

Answer (score 1):

its very easy in three step

1. drag web browser from toolbox
2. in the properties of web browser go to URL and paste the address of your SWF file
3. now run the application